# accessing my Server (ESXI) from external network

Tags: server, vsphere, esxi

I have a server  `ESXI`  (192.168.8.100) and i need to access it remotely from outside my network  `(https)` .

I have got a  `DDNS`   `account from 'No-ip.com (server.ddns.com)`

i have forwarded port  `( 443,80,22,21)`  and make the configuration of the host name in my router But still i can't access my  `ESXI`  server(192.168.8.100). Could you please help me if there is any configuration is missing ? I just need to access it from outside my network.

Answer (score 0):

please verify that you added your router ip as Gateway in your esxi and esxi and router in same network subnet